# CMake: Generator expression in a target property is not evaluated

Tags: c, cmake

I am going to use zlib in my project. I have to build the zlib project for Win32.

Let the minimum very simplified zlib project and my project to look like below

```
zlib/
  CMakeLists.txt
  zlib.h  // empty file
  zlib.c  // empty file
1.c
CMakeLists.txt
```

My very simplified project that depends on zlib:

**zlib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(zlib C)
add_library(zlib STATIC zlib.c zlib.h)
```

**1.c**

```
#include "zlib.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(prg C)
if(WIN32)  # Set variables for find_package
  set(ZLIB_ROOT ./zlib)
  set(ZLIB_LIBRARY $<TARGET_FILE:zlib>)
  add_subdirectory(./zlib)
endif()
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
add_executable(prg 1.c)
target_link_libraries(prg ZLIB::ZLIB)
```

I run `cmake .`, then `cmake --build .`, and get the error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '$<TARGET_FILE:zlib>.obj' [C:\tmp\cmake\prg.vcxproj]
```

Why the generator expression is not evaluated if I use target properties ZLIB::ZLIB and how to fix this? I expect the expressions evaluated according to the cmake manual [LOCATION](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LOCATION.html).

```
target_include_directories(prg PRIVATE ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(prg ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

If I replace `target_link_libraries(prg ZLIB::ZLIB)` with the lines above, then the project is built successfully, although `ZLIB_LIBRARIES` contains the value `$<TARGET_FILE:zlib>`.  I don't want to replace use of target properties since they are actually used in a 3rd party project, and I wish to avoid modifying cmake files of a 3rd party project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake generator expressions are only evaluated at build time. Normally it would work if you were using `target_link_libraries(prg ${ZLIB_LIBRARY})` instead of  `target_link_libraries(prg ZLIB::ZLIB)`. It is however possible to link your own zlib library by creating an [ALIAS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#alias-libraries).

In this way, by creating an `[ZLIB::ZLIB][2]` alias before calling `find_package` it will prevent [FindZLIB.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindZLIB.cmake) creating the library itself.

`ZLIB_LIBRARY` can be any non-empty value and is ignored and so generator expression is not needed.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(prg C)

add_subdirectory(./zlib)

if(WIN32)
  set(ZLIB_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/zlib)
  set(ZLIB_LIBRARY $<TARGET_FILE:zlib>)
endif()

add_library(ZLIB::ZLIB ALIAS zlib)
set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ZLIB_ROOT})

find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)

add_executable(prg 1.c)

target_link_libraries(prg ZLIB::ZLIB)
```